# Getting full member name from ComputerManagement using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am using these commands to fetch the members of the Administrators group using PowerShell:

```
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$s,computer"
$group = $computer.PSBase.Children.Find('Administrators', 'Group') 
$Admin_Accounts = $group.PSBase.Invoke("members") | ForEach {
  $_.GetType().InvokeMember("FullName", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
}
```

However, the results I am getting are just member names 'NAME' and not the full name displayed in the UI as 'ADomain/NAME'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother with ADSI. Use WMI instead:

```
$group = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group -Filter "Name='Administrators'"
$group.GetRelated('Win32_UserAccount') | Select-Object -Expand Caption
```

Comment: For a group of servers, if i have to fire it remotely, ADSI works fine. WMI is executing very slowly.
Dont we have a way to achieve it via ADSI only ?

Comment: Also, the results are to go into an excel sheet. Fetching it from remote server and then putting results in an excel is a slow process. Can you please suggest me something in ADSI only ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Powershell version you could use.

```
(Get-LocalGroupMember -Name Administrators).Name
```

This wil show all members of the local administrators group like this:

```
domain-or-computername\username
```

Tested on v5